# adding current and future dates to an array

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsmutablearray, nsdate

I am creating a custom type calendar and I am trying to see if it is possible to store dates in an array without statically assigning each one.  For example the 1st date in the array would be the day it was first created and it would save the next week lets say into the relevant indexes in the array.

```
NSMutableArray *thisWeek = [today, tomorrow, sunday(Feb 24), monday (Feb 25), etc];
```

What would be the best way to go about storing the future dates?

Comment: Did not get your question. however you can store dates in array, there is no issue in that.

Comment: My question is how do I store a weeks worth of dates in an array with the first date being today?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray *days = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; 
NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *tempCop = [cal components:NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit
                                   fromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSDate *today = [cal dateFromComponents:tempCop];

for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) 
{
    NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc]init];
    [comps setDay:i];
    [days addObject:[cal dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:today options:0]];     
}
```

Comment: Any way to store it without the time?

Comment: Use - (NSDateComponents *)components:(NSUInteger)unitFlags fromDate:(NSDate *)date to create components from current date. Pass unit flags as (NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit).

Comment: Could you possible update that into your answer.  I am having a litte trouble figuring out how to add it in.  Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSMutableArray *days;
days = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; 

NSDate *todayDate = [NSDate Date];
[days addObject:todayDate]; 

for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++) 
{
    NSDate *newDate = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24*i];

    [days addObject:newDate];

}
```

In this way, you can add days in array.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `dateByAddingTimeInterval:` in the `NSDate` docs ([link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html)). It lets you add a given amount of seconds to a date.